# How to minimise differences between a development and production server?

Tags: production

Lots of time, We build a web application in our own personal system, with a local server that comes in packages like WAMP, XAMPP. But, the configuration we have on our system hardly matches 100% with the server where we host that application. This adds up to the debugging complexity a lot. Specially when the server you host is configured to hide the errors. Relying on error logs to debug everything, is a uncomfortable options, which is also not guaranteed to be available.

What are the measures we can take to minimise such differences?

You guys might say, it depends on web server as the configuration might be different from server to server. Even in this case, or shared hosting, I would like to know of the pointers to take, before hosting a application or even start building it.

Comment: I use a Xen-based VPS, and have installed a Xen-based VPS with the same configuration locally. I think you even can use snapshots to get the exact same configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a staging server that is a clone of our deployment server. Running code by the staging server (using version control) is both fast and a reliable way to ensure that the new code/code changes work as expected on the live environment.

That said, we use Ubuntu servers and I've opted to use Ubuntu as my development environment as well, makes stuff so much easier.

Comment: Still, does not give me a proper solution to implement.

Comment: I have a lamp installed on my Ubuntu as well. Does this really minimises the differences?

Comment: In the end it depends on your server configuration. What we do on top of using similar operating systems, is making sure the PHP and MySQL versions are the same on development and live environments. We also use the same configuration files (php.ini, my.cnf) on both machines. So far everything done locally has worked flawlessy on live.

Other things to take into consideration is to edit /etc/hosts so that the address of your website actually points to local environment. Then everything should work the same way. Ofcourse, comment out the hosts line whenever checking the live site.